# VARCHAR2 Becomes Numeric by passing as parameter to a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on a school work and I have an error in my code.
I have created a PLSQL package:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE GestionProjets AS

  TYPE Signaletique IS TABLE OF EMPLOYES%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
  TYPE TableNomDep IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40);

  PROCEDURE AjouterProjets(ProjetRecord IN PROJETS%ROWTYPE);
  PROCEDURE SupprimerProjet(DelNumPro IN PROJETS.numpro%TYPE);
  --PROCEDURE ModifierProjet(newRecord IN PROJETS%ROWTYPE, oldRecord IN PROJETS%ROWTYPE);
  FUNCTION ListerEmployes(dep1 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE, dep2 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE) RETURN Signaletique;

END GestionProjets;
```

That's the body of the function where I have an error:

```
  FUNCTION ListerEmployes(dep1 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE, dep2 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE) RETURN Signaletique AS

    nomDeps TableNomDep;
    SigTable Signaletique;
    EXWrongDep1 EXCEPTION;
    EXWrongDep2 EXCEPTION;

  BEGIN

    SELECT Nomdep 
    BULK COLLECT INTO nomDeps
    FROM DEPARTEMENTS;

    -- test if dep 1 est un parametre valide
    IF NOT nomDeps.exists(dep1) THEN
      RAISE EXWrongDep1;
    END IF;

    -- test if dep 2 est un parametre valide
    IF NOT nomDeps.exists(dep2) THEN
      RAISE EXWrongDep2;
    END IF;




    EXCEPTION
      WHEN EXWrongDep1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20008, 'MAUVAIS PARAMETRE: ' || dep1 || ' N EXISTE PAS!');
      WHEN EXWrongDep2 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20008, 'MAUVAIS PARAMETRE: ' || dep2 || ' N EXISTE PAS!');
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20007, 'ERREUR INCONNU: ' ||  SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);

  END ListerEmployes;
```

When I try to execute the function, i get this error message:

```
DECLARE
  tabel gestionprojets.Signaletique;
BEGIN
  tabel := gestionprojets.listeremployes('sdsd','sdsd');
END;


ORA-20007: ERREUR INCONNU: -6502 - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "EDGE.GESTIONPROJETS", line 108
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

I don't understand why I get this error message. The type of the Nomdep column is VARCHAR2(40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the table type is indexed by BINARY_INTEGER.  When the `.EXISTS` calls are executed they're passed either `dep1` or `dep2` as the index for the table, and thus PL/SQL tries to convert the VARCHAR2(40) parameter to a BINARY_INTEGER.  Since these input parameters are both non-numeric character strings ('sdsd') the conversion fails.

This code might run faster if, instead of reading the entire `DEPARTEMENTS` table into memory each time `ListerEmployes` is called, it was rewritten as

```
FUNCTION ListerEmployes(dep1 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE, dep2 IN DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdep%TYPE) RETURN Signaletique
AS
  strNomdep  DEPARTEMENTS.Nomdp%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- test if dep 1 est un parametre valide

  BEGIN
    SELECT NOMDEP
      INTO strNomdep
      FROM DEPARTEMENTS
      WHERE NOMDEP = dep1;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20008, 'MAUVAIS PARAMETRE: ' || dep1 || ' N EXISTE PAS!'); 
  END;

  -- test if dep 2 est un parametre valide

  BEGIN
    SELECT NOMDEP
      INTO strNomdep
      FROM DEPARTEMENTS
      WHERE NOMDEP = dep2;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20008, 'MAUVAIS PARAMETRE: ' || dep2 || ' N EXISTE PAS!'); 
  END;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20007, 'ERREUR INCONNU: ' ||  SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);    
END ListerEmployes;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Mischa - I don't think this is "stupid".  Everybody does things like this sometimes.  You had a problem, you asked a question, you got an answer.  And so it goes...